# Related rates problems: A general question

Tags: calculus

I want to really understand related rates, and there is one thing that I don't truly understand that has been bugging me, and I think a lot of people here will be able to give a simple explanation.

An example:

Let's say the problem is about a cone with greatest radius 4 ft (top) and greatest height 10 ft. Due to the relationships in a cone, we can say that:

$r=\frac{2}{5}h$

The cone is leaking with a rate of $\frac{dV}{dt}=-5\frac{ft^3}{min}$, and we're asked to find the change of $h$ at $h=6 ft$.

Now comes my question: Why can I not just find the value for $r=\frac{2}{5}* 6 ft$, and then plot it into the formula $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$ and solve for $\frac{dh}{dt}$? Why do I have to rewrite the expression, substituting r for h: $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{4}{25}\pi h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$?

I understand how to get there and what to do, but I do not understand why finding the value for $r$ does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Because both $r$ and $h$ are changing with time.

Longer answer: With your method, you are treating $r$ as constant, which it is not.  We need to think of $V=\frac13 \pi r^2 h$ as giving volume in terms of the two changing quantities $r$ and $h$.  We could apply product rule in taking a time derivative: $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac13\pi\left(r^2\frac{dh}{dt}+2rh\frac{dr}{dt}\right)$.  Or we can substitute $r=\frac{2}{5}h$ and deal with the single changing variable $h$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understood!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad I could help!